# jQuery not working in any browser in Windows 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, windows-8.1

jQuery is not working on my Windows 8.1 64-bit machine. Is there any known issue that causes that?

Have tried both CDN (Google, jQuery), and local sources, but none work. I know the code is correct because I've tried various examples to verify, including old code that worked fine before, and code from this YouTube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRnQOcVclS8

I've tried using this script source also, to no avail:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to test: click on a paragraph tag, and it should hide. Click on an H1 tag, and it should toggle open or closed. None of this works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Heading one</h1>
    <p>This is just some text for heading 1</p>

    <h1>Heading two</h1>
    <p>This is just some text for heading 2</p>

    <h1>Heading three</h1>
    <p>This is just some text for heading 3</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("p").hide();

            $("h1").click(function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
            });

        });
</script>
</html>
```

None of it is working. Not sure what is going on.

### Update

Several helpful commenters have tested my code and it appears to work fine on their machines, which really is helpful to narrow down the issue. It has been established that my code is good. So, at this point, to anyone who would offer help, I'm looking for specific information, "known issues", or "gotchas" on why this isn't working for me. I suspect it has something to do with Window 8 or Windows 8.1, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: The answer is below but looking in the dev console of your browser also would have made this pretty clear.  Use your tools!

Comment: Hi Robert: That is not the answer, just an unfortunate typo when I was posting. I've corrected the posted code and am still looking for assistance. Are you able to run the corrected code fine in your browser? Just curious because that would help me narrow this issue down a little more. Thanks for your reply

Comment: This works fine. im using windows 7. it works in google ff and ie

Comment: Thanks for testing this ejay. That helps me to feel confident that my code is good. I've added an update requesting only people with advanced knowledge of Windows respond, since this may turn out to be not one of your run-of-the-mill, easy answer questions. Still seeking help. Thanks again.

Comment: What does the dev console of your browser say?  There is definitely not a bug in Windows 8.1 that prevents jquery from working across all browsers.  The bug is in your code somewhere.

Comment: [Pasted it into JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3sPT/) and it seems to work. Maybe you're unable to load resources from `code.jquery.com` because of firewall rules? Have you tried using a local copy of that `.js` file?

Comment: FYI, it all seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3aMea/.  You apparently either have some other error or have something blocking resources from loading.

Comment: Thansk tadman and jfriend. I guess worst case scenario, I realize that I can use JSFiddle to test the code at least. Tadman: yes, I have tried multiple local sources and have doublechecked the paths, to no avail. I'm going to see if there is a safemode for Win 8.1 and try it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems trying to run code from my computer before, so I just use JSFiddle. If that's not an option for you, trying disabling security settings that you prevent you from running code that's stored on your computer. That or get a website to run it off of.

If you have VisualStudio, you can run code in there and it will work. Just create a blank app and replace all the code and remove references to WinJS. You can get an express version if you don't. Sorry if that's not your preferred option. That was my work-around before I got JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Josh. I ended up being able to successfully test my code by copying the jQuery part into Firefox dev console, and running the jQuerify plugin. The equivalent pluin for Chrome does not work though. The problem of why I can't run jQuery (or PHP even) on my laptop is still not solved, but your suggestions are helpful and I will try them and report back.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO HELPED WITH THIS ISSUE! After long consideration I choosing Josh's answer as accepted. The reason for this is that though others were able to help by verifying that my code worked, Josh offered a comprehensive list of solutions specific to Windows and indicated that he had also faced the same problem. Thanks again for your kind assistance everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It is good that you spotted my typo, but unfortunately that is not the cause of the error. I fixed it to your good suggestion, but it still does not work, in any browser.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the issue is as it's working in Chrome, FF and IE for me (on Windows 8.1).

Comment: Well that definitely helps kpo! I guess my next step is to see if maybe disabling antivirus might help? I thought about disabling extensions and addons, because I test mostly with Chrome and FF, but it doesn't even work in IE. Thanks for taking the effort to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try With

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $("p").hide();

            $("h1").click(function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
            });

        });
```

Add `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js`
instead of `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/aAP5A/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution ended up being removing Amazon Wishlist plugin. I guess it doesn't play nice with jQuery.

Comment: EDIT: The comment above was premature --> This was not the solution. :(